# How to prevent piping to `less` in Rust from overwriting the shell prompt?

Tags: rust, subprocess, exec, stdin

Running this program:

```
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};
use std::io::{self, Write};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut child = Command::new("less")
        .args(["--quit-if-one-screen"])
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()?;
    let child_stdin = child.stdin.as_mut().unwrap();
    child_stdin.write_all(b"Hello, world!\n")?;
    drop(child_stdin);

    Ok(())
}
```

Overwrites the prompt with the output being piped to `less`, e.g., it looks something like this, and I have to hit enter a couple of times to get my prompt back:

```
% cargo run --bin pager
   Compiling single v0.1.0 (/Users/robenkleene/Developer/Scratch/Rust/single)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.13s
     Running `target/debug/pager`
Hello, world!
```

I want it to look like this, e.g., the prompt re-appears correctly after the program runs:

```
% cargo run --bin pager
   Compiling single v0.1.0 (/Users/robenkleene/Developer/Scratch/Rust/single)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.00s
     Running `target/debug/pager`
Hello, world!
%
```

Comment: For me, its working correctly. i.e after the bytes are written to stdin of child process. program completes and prompt appears right after it.

Comment: The shell and terminal emulator you use might be relevant, can reproduce on `alacritty`+`bash` but not on `zsh` maybe how you setup your promt there, too.

Comment: I suggest adding `child.wait()?;` at the end.

Comment: @SvenMarnach `child.wait()?;` solved it. If you add this as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using `drop` on a `&mut` does nothing. You probably want to drop the actual stdin handle, which you can do by taking it out of the `Child` struct.

```rs
let mut child_stdin = child.stdin.take().unwrap();
child_stdin.write_all(b"Hello, world!\n")?;
drop(child_stdin);
```

Comment: Well you can't use the reference any more after that (unlike with a shared one which is `Copy`) but you're right it probably doesn't have the desired effect. The problem is that doesn't help with the prompt being overwritten.